# Avoid file_get_contents of a file giving me headers before the contents

Tags: php, http-headers, file-get-contents

I've created a file with `file_put_contents()` with a text "*En un lugar de la mancha*". I want to get that file from another php using `file_get_contents` and (for instance) print the output.

The problem is that I'm getting also the headers:

> Content-type: text/html X-Powered-By: PHP/4.3.9 En un lugar de la Mancha

Why? I just want to get the contents of the file..How can I avoid it? I've tried with `file()` but with the same result (first two elements of the array are headers)

Comment: Are you really using PHP 4.3? You really need to consider upgrading to at least 5.4, since there's numerous issues unfixed in the PHP 4 family.

Comment: jejeje yes I am. I told that to my boss (he is the admin of the server) like 1000 times... hopefully we will change in a few mounths

Comment: Whenever you have that conversation be sure to show him this page http://php.net/eol.`php 4.3 | 31 Mar 2005 | 9 years, 10 months ago`

Comment: 4.3? You just may be able to sue him for inhuman working conditions...

Comment: yes, it's cruel. I'm currently working on parallel processes with that... no fork, no gearman, no multi_curl... you can have an idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not the headers of the file, but part of the text. 
Chances are you added the headers to the file content when used file_put_content (headers are sent by the server, they are not part of the file itself).

Comment: Your right ^^, they are in the files. Do you know how to avoid it?